# Authenticate to API with secret key and credentials

Tags: api, authentication, oauth

I am trying to make a request to the [TaskRabbit API](https://www.taskrabbit.com/api/v2/explorer#e38fffb110e0d48df5b56df5888cb529). I want to use my credentials and get the details of my account back. 
I have a developer account (application ID, application Secret, Authorize URL). How can I use these credentials to authenticate with TaskRabbit? Can I use something like curl to test this out?

I tried using something like

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"my username","password":"my password"}' https://combo-staging-2.taskrabbit.in/api/v2/account.json
```

this fails, since it’s not what the API expects. Is there a way to use my keys to make a similar request?

Comment: It is mentioned in the documentation that you are required to authenticate.  Did you look at the [Authentication API](https://www.taskrabbit.com/api/v2/explorer#7425c23e69d2492e67df00fd127cdf8f) where they discuss how you can connect via the API?

Comment: You may also want to look at their documentation on [authenticating](https://www.taskrabbit.com/api/v2/explorer#6017ee53e6cea6b255bac0820436df9a).

Comment: Thanks! it actually turned out I need to request a token from them with my keys that I will use in any subsequent call.